# Using ADF Copy Activity, I need to unzip and convert .seq files in .zip to csv

Tags: azure-data-factory

This scenario is new for me. My storage account having multiple folders. 1 folder contains few .txt files and  .zip files.
.zip files contains .seq files.

My requirement is need to look in to each folder and

1. copy .txt files
2. unzip zip files
3. files(.seq) in zip folder to be convert to .csv.

Sink to destination.

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to show your work: what did you try? Where are you stuck? What errors or output issues do you have? As written, you've only provided a set of requirements, with no details about what you've done.

Answer (score 1):

Get the list of folders from the container, copy .txt files to sink folder and unzip and copy seq files to sink, convert seq files to CSV and delete seq files from the folder.

[image]

**Part1:**

1. Using the `Get Metadata` activity get the folders list.

[image]

[image]

2. Pass the output of `Get Metadata1` to ForEach activity.

`@activity('get folder list').output.childItems`

[image]

3. Inside the `ForEach` activity, add 2 copy activities.

[image]

Copy data activity1:

In one `copy data` activity, unzip the zip files and copy to sink.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Copy data activity2:

[image]

[image]

**Part2:**

1. Get seq files where they are copied to in previous activities.

[image]

2. Pass the `GetMetadata2` activity output to `ForEach2` activity. Copy each ‘seq’ file and convert it to CSV using copy data activity.

[image]

Parameterize the sink file name and replace extension `seq` with `CSV`.

`@replace(item().name,'.seq','.csv')`

[image]

**Part3:**

As seq files were not deleted while converting them to CSV, we can use `delete` activity to delete them from the folder.

[image]

Comment: FYI the OP had no specific question and showed no attempt, no code, no issue, no errors... This isn't something that should be answered (you essentially wrote them a custom blog post / document) - this isn't how Stack Overflow is set up to work. (see my comment under the question)